# how to make a robot stand after it has fallen

Tags: stability

I have seen the methods to make a bipedal robot stand and walk keeping its center of gravity in stable mode, but how can i make the robot stand if it falls in ground? For example right now i'm using valkyrie robot in a gazebo, but the problem is once it falls in ground i've to again restart the simulator or respawn the robot. hers the screen shot of this:
[image]

In internet also their are methods describing ways to make a bipedal robot stable while walking and standing but no way to make it stand after its fallen state. So if anyone knows the method or algorithm or have any reference than you can tell me.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* DineshLama, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: You are always welcome to ask off-topic questions in [chat]. If you're looking for the source of algorithms, especially for a particular robot, my advice would always be to look at journal articles and/or contact the team that produced the robot. If no methods or papers exist that describe how to accomplish the feat, then you could consider it an open problem.